# django - check if form data exists in request

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views

This is a crazy question, I know, but I just want to make sure.

There is this code in `Django`:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
     do_something()
```

It checks if the form was really submitted in POST method. My question is: does it also check if there is a form data in request at all? I mean, I could take the `preview` page's url and just visit this link without filling form fields. Does this check above detect this case?

If it does not check for form data existence, how can I achieve this? Btw, I am not using `Django` `forms`. I am just receiving data in view like this:

```
data['year'] = request.POST.get('year')
```

and all validation is happening in frontend with `Javascript`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First of all, I encourage you all to go for django-forms.** I will also switch to django forms step by step from now on.

but for those who missed something beautiful like django forms like me - this is a quick solution for checking if there is form data at all inside request body.

```
if len(request.body) > 0: 
  # there is something inside request body
else: 
  # random link visit and no form data at all
```

here is more about [HttpRequest.body](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.body)

Answer (score 1):

Nope, this is just a `HTTP Request` method check.

In order to check if the form data is there (if form validates), call [`is_valid()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.is_valid) on the [`Form`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form) instance.

Comment: @doniyor ok, then how does your actual view handling the post request look? Thanks.

Comment: @doniyor also, what is the reason for not using django forms?

Comment: I updated the question now. I am catching form like this: ``data['year'] = request.POST.get('year')``. I had some problems using bootstrap and django forms, then back in the days, i decided not to use django forms. I thought, i didnot lose many things by that

Comment: @doniyor Django uses Forms extensively and with powerful methods (validation, saving, model handling), saying I didn't loose many things is misleading to people who actually are trying to learn, problems of bootstrap with Django is not an excuse not to use the full power of the stack (btw django-crispy-forms allows you to use whatever you want from bootstrap).

Comment: @petkostas you are totally right. I unfortunately missed that great feature of django. I will switch to forms step by step now. 99% of all django people use forms. I am the only dangling node i think. thanks for mentioning crispy-forms. i will go for it

Comment: @doniyor comment was not made to offend you or anything else, if it made you feel like that, just a small note.

Comment: @petkostas no man, not at all. it is rather a great advice, thank you. I had always bad feeling not using django-forms. nowadays, it really hurts, i have to write a lot js to validate. I have 2 milestones: 1) django class-based views 2) django-forms. :D

Answer (score 1):

That only checks the method, it does not check for form data.  There are some uses of the POST method that does not include form data, for instance if all of the information needed to create a resource is in the URL.

If you are using Django's form system, form validation will of course fail to pass if there is no form data.

Comment: I dont use django forms :(

Comment: If you are not using a form validation system like Django forms, then what will happen in your view if a user somehow submits a POST request without form data depends on what you're doing with the data.  It will very likely raise an exception that will result in a 500 error if it is not caught.  Be sure to test this case and make sure you understand what your program is doing!

Comment: sure, i am catching all exceptions which might raise 500.

Comment: Okay.  Be sure you are not using JS validation as a replacement for serverside validation -- it is trivial to bypass JS validation deliberately or by accident, at which point improper data can easily get in.

Comment: yeah, thanks for great advice. I mostly validated with js in frontend. so i need to double-check in backend also then.

Comment: Yes.  My team uses both Django forms AND frontend validation.

Comment: wow, then it is very stable. i wish i could have started with django forms. now it is too late, i am almost ready with the project. I am reading now the docs about ``HttpRequest``, cannot find any attribute to check if form is submitted. there must be somewhere, i am hopefully not the first one to face this issue, right?

Comment: I found ``HttpRequest.body`` which is a String. is it the form data in requestbody? I can check like ``if request.body!=""``, right? i will check it now

Comment: I would not bother checking explicitly if a form is submitted.  Whether form data exists or not is irrelevant; if form data does not exist, than it will fail your validation step like any other invalid submission or, if you have no validation (again, you should!) then it will throw an exception when you try to fetch data from the request, which you can catch.  However, if you are really determined to check this explicitly, `if not request.body:` might work.

Comment: yes actually you are right. but let me check this explicitly for now :D